# Perplexing Ruby/MySQL Error: "invalid packet: sequence number mismatch"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running a Rails app with MySQL on Heroku and this error has me totally perplexed.  Everything works fine if I try to select a single row, often if I try to select a handful.  But if I try to select *, or even a few dozen/hundred records, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::ProtocolError: invalid packet: sequence number mismatch(52 != 29(expected)): SELECT  `people`.* FROM `people` LIMIT 30 OFFSET 10
/home/slugs/70bb5dad-9387-46c4-935d-cf74e70276a8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `log'
/home/slugs/70bb5dad-9387-46c4-935d-cf74e70276a8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:289:in `execute'
/home/slugs/70bb5dad-9387-46c4-935d-cf74e70276a8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:619:in `select'
/home/slugs/70bb5dad-9387-46c4-935d-cf74e70276a8/mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
```

Running Rails 3, Ruby 1.8.6, and MySQL 5.1.42.

I'm truly at my wit's end here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

David

Comment: genkilabs' answer seems to be correct...

Answer (score 11):

Looks similar to a bug in the ruby-mysql connector when you try and run will_paginate with all, such as @author.books.all.paginate(...)

https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/issues#issue/8

the quick fix there is to move back to gem ruby-mysql 2.9.3

Check for known bugs in whichever mysql connector gem you are running

Comment: Helps, me, too.  What I like about ruby-mysql is you don't have all that weird config to do on install, like in the other answer...

Comment: This just changed the error to invalid packet: f1="\x0F\xC0\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"

Comment: I had to downgrade, and remove that line of code as well – but it worked! Thanks.  If anyone is wondering how to find that line of code, you can find your gems directory with `gem env`, then if you cd to that dir and type `vi gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.3/lib/mysql/protocol.rb +666` you'll be at the line of code.  I blogged my tales here: http://omegadelta.net/2011/05/25/mysqlprotocolerror-with-ruby-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to get my setup working (in Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 mysql-client-5.1 libmysqlclient-dev
sudo gem install mysql
```

Make sure you are using the mysql gem and not something else (like ruby-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

In my situation downgrading to ruby-mysql 2.9.3 didn't solve it completely.

I also had to update this file:
https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql/commit/07ddfafafbd1d46bbb71c7cb54ae0f03bc998d27

And just to clear this problem out,
ruby-mysql 2.9.4 works perfectly well on ubuntu 10.04, but not in macos - snow leopard.

Comment: Not entirely true: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS and I get the same error with 2.9.4.  2.9.3 does seem to work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a rails3 app and what resolved it was to downgrade ruby from version 2.0.0 to version 1.9.3.