# Rails - Mysql::ProtocolError: invalid packet

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jrubyonrails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perplexing Ruby/MySQL Error: "invalid packet: sequence number mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748091/perplexing-ruby-mysql-error-invalid-packet-sequence-number-mismatch)

My rails app just started having these strange MySQL errors on my EC2/RDS stack.

I've tried several versions of ruby 1.9.2 as well as REE 1.8.7.

What's the deal with this ProtocolError?  This doesn't happen on any of my other sites or my local machine.

I can delete some data from my site and the query will work for a couple of page views then it breaks again :(

I'm using Phusion with Apache.

with version gem 'ruby-mysql', "2.9.4"

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in TricksController#index

Mysql::ProtocolError: invalid packet: sequence number mismatch(103 != 29(expected)): SELECT `tricks`.* FROM `tricks`
```

And with version gem 'ruby-mysql', "2.9.3"

```
Mysql::ProtocolError (invalid packet: f1="\x0F\xC0\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of: [Perplexing Ruby/MySQL Error: "invalid packet: sequence number mismatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748091/perplexing-ruby-mysql-error-invalid-packet-sequence-number-mismatch)

My Rails 3.0.4 app started working with ruby-mysql 2.9.3.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?